# Detect when element's left position has reached an specific value

Tags: jquery

I need an alert to show when the ul contained on a DIV, that adds a negative left value on each click (on left, moving it to that side), reaches it's parent left position with it's left side.

I have tried to store maximum value that ul's left attribute should have (it seems to store the correct value), but no alert shows when that value is reached (see "if" statement).

Here's the code, and above a jsFiddle example.

```
$('.logo').on('click',function(){
      infoMax=$('.infoGallery ul').width()-$('.infoGallery').width();

      $('.infoGallery ul').css('left',"-=200" );

      if ($('.infoGallery ul').css('left') <= -infoMax){
      alert("yay");}
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1juv00ka/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1juv00ka/4/

Very simple modification :

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
    infoMax = $('.infoGallery ul').width() - $('.infoGallery').width();
    $('.infoGallery ul').css('left', "-=200");
    if (parseInt($('.infoGallery ul').css('left'), 10) <= -infoMax) {//if you don't parseInt, you get a string like "500px"
        alert("yay");
    }
});
```

Comment: So simple... it wasn't an integer. Thanks. I'll tick in 9 minutes